# material-ui: need help hiding dropdown icon in <Select>

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Select component from material-ui. In the documentation of material-ui, it is said that you can override the CSS from the components using the tag  sx={{ ... }}. I need to style the component with className of '.MuiSvgIcon-root-393', which is a SVG child of 'Select', and is the dropdown icon. Here is my attempt, but is not working:

```
import { Select } from '@material-ui/core'

<Select
    sx={{
      '.MuiSvgIcon-root-393': {
        visibility: 'hidden'
      }
    }}
>
    ....
<Select/>
```

What I am really trying to do is to make the Select arrow hidden.

I would appreciate some help in how to proceed with this, and/or any tips.

Comment: your `sx` is inside the `<Select>` props?

Comment: it is not, sorry. Just edited @DavidYappeter

Comment: try this `& .MuiSvgIcon-root-393` maybe. or playaround with the other props in `Select` like `inputProps`, `MenuProps`.

Comment: not working, @DavidYappeter

Comment: Does this solve your issue? https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/26473. Looks like they just remove the icon, and adjust the padding to reclaim the space it would've taken up.

Comment: if you want to post it as an answer i will give you the solved badge @ncasale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think this will solve your problem.

[github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/26473](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/26473)

Looks like they just remove the icon, and adjust the padding to reclaim the space it would've taken up.